Only HDMI audio output available while audio jacks are not shown (Ubuntu 24.04)
I have an Intel B660 chipset motherboard with an AMD video card, there is also a logitech stream cam with a mic.
After upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 the audio jacks of the motherboard stopped working. I was previously using a headset connected to the audio jack. But now, the device isn't showing up, regardless if I plug it into the front jack or the back jack of the board.
For audio output in the sound mixer, the only device listed is 'HDMI DisplayPort 2 Navi21/23 HDMI Audio Controller'. There are no other options regardless of what is in the audio jacks.
pacmd list-cards
3 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.usb-046d_Logitech_StreamCam_127E0DC5-02>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 21
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "Logitech StreamCam"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Logitech StreamCam at usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1.2:1.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.2/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-046d_Logitech_StreamCam_127E0DC5-02"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "046d"
        device.vendor.name = "Logitech, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0893"
        device.product.name = "StreamCam"
        device.serial = "046d_Logitech_StreamCam_127E0DC5"
        device.form_factor = "webcam"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "StreamCam"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 65, available: unknown)
        input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (priority 55, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <input:analog-stereo>
    sources:
        alsa_input.usb-046d_Logitech_StreamCam_127E0DC5-02.analog-stereo/#1: StreamCam Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        iec958-stereo-input: Digital Input (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 22
    properties:
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0x81320000 irq 166"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:03:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "ab28"
        device.product.name = "Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio Controller"
        device.string = "2"
        device.description = "Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 38468, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo-extra1>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1/#1: Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor/#2: Monitor of Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "Pavilion 27q"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 2
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 23
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6212120000 irq 169"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "7ad0"
        device.product.name = "Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"

aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [Pavilion 27q]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

sudo dmesg |grep -e "snd" -e "sound"
[    0.931493] ata8.00: Features: Trust Dev-Sleep NCQ-sndrcv
[    5.901057] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.901283] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.901549] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.902109] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: Force to non-snoop mode
[    5.911845] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input24
[    5.911887] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input25
[    5.911913] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input26
[    5.911944] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input27
[    5.911983] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input28
[    5.933873] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input29
[    5.933915] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input30
[    5.933951] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input31
[    5.933972] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input32
[    5.945652] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[    7.591453] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: bound 0000:03:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])



